# Referencing webcontrols in an UpdatePanel in EditItemTemplate of a Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, edititemtemplate

I am getting null reference exception when trying to reference a web control which is within an AJAX UpdatePanel, which itself is within and EditItemTemplate of a Gridview. I am doing this in the RowDataBound event handler of the gridview as follows:

```
protected void gvIntakes_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            DataRowView row = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            UpdatePanel up = (UpdatePanel)e.Row.FindControl("Status_UpdatePanel"); //**** up is showing null on debug
            Panel pnlSelectStaff = (Panel) up.FindControl("pnlSelectStaff")  ;
            Panel pnlSchedule = (Panel)up.FindControl("pnlSchedule");
```

Comment: You should not place `UpdatePanel` inside `gvIntake` instead it should be outside of `gvIntake`.

Comment: Thank you. This is by design. I have intentionaly put the update panel in the gridview to prevent girdview refresh when editing rows. Thanks any way!

Comment: ***It is not how you use `UpdatePanel`.*** If you place `UpdatePanel` inside Grid like you did now, only way to refresh the grid with new data is to Reload the page with `Response.Redirect`. (If that is the case, then you do not even need `UpdatePanel`)

Comment: Yes I am aware of it. I don't need to refresh the gridview. I have search filters and button at the top of the page to refresh the gridview data.